# How to convert between decimal and hex?

Tags: r, hex, decimal

I am running the code below in R, and it doesn't return the original decimal number.

```
as.hexmode(-8192)
"ffffe000"

strtoi(c("ffffe000"))
NA
```

Answer (score 5):

The `strtoi` function takes a string as an input (see [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strtoi.html)). However, the `as.hexmode` function does not return an integer but rather a hexadecimal representation of the input, which is not a string (it is a type named `hexmode` AFAIK).

The proper solution, as suggested by the [R documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/hexmode.html), is using `as.integer` to obtain your original input:

```
> strtoi(as.hexmode(-8192),16)
[1] NA
> as.integer(as.hexmode(-8192))
[1] -8192
```

It remains unclear to me whether the problem is with using a negative input. I can only suppose `strtoi` handles only unsigned ints.